# Actual page number and Contents page number do not match

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

The page number indicated in the contents sections and the actual page number do not match up. [image: Contents page]

The Abstract should start at page i, List of abbreviations should start on page iv. While Acknowledgements, Contents, and list of figures are numbered correctly, the list figures is on a completely different scheme !

I have been using ..

```
\documentclass[12pt, parskip=full]{report}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[letterpaper, left=1.5in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in,]{geometry}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{tocbibind}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\pagenumbering{roman}   
\input{abstr}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}

\input{ack}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgements}

\input{abbrev}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Abbreviations}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables


\pagenumbering{arabic}  
\part{Introduction}
\input{intro}
```

For the chapters titled Abstract, Acknowledgements and List of Abbreviations, I'm using the command:

```
\*chapter{Chapter Name}
```

Any help as to how to get the page numbering correctly would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance !

EDIT: Page number of the section List of Tables have been corrected by using

```
\clearpage
```

after

```
\listoftables
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Surely, you mean `\chapter*`, not `\*chapter`. And the `\addcontentsline` commands are too late then, they occur after `\input`. They should put right after `\chapter*`

Comment: Sorry about that, I did mean `\chapter*`.
And putting `\addcontentsline' right after `\chapter*` fixed the problem. Thank you so much !

Comment: You could also use this: https://github.com/johannesbottcher/unnumberedtotoc

Answer (score 1):

In order for the chapter title and its corresponding entry in the ToC to have the same page number, the issue of `\chapter*` and `\addcontentsline` should be done on the same page (`\chapter` already includes a call to `\addcontentsline` so they will appear on the same page).

Using

```
\input{<chapter-file>.tex}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{<chapter title>}
```

will only work if the contents of `<chapter-file>.tex` doesn't exceed the setting of a single page. And this is rarely the case for a "chapter", in general.

Your solution would be one of the following approaches:

1. Include the line

   ```
   \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{<chapter title>}
   ```

   as part of your `<chapter-file>.tex` immediately following the `\chapter*` command.
2. If you don't have access to `<chapter-file>.tex`, or wish to keep the chapter text separate from layout constructions, you can also use

   ```
   \cleardoublepage
   \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{<chapter title>}
   \input{<chapter-file>}
   ```

   Since `\addcontentsline` doesn't set any content, the `\chapter*` issued within `\input{<chapter-file>}` will still occur on the same page and therefore provide the correct page within the ToC.
3. Automate the process by using switches: `\addstarchaptertotoc` starts the insertion of `\chapter*`'s titles into the ToC while `\removestarchapterfromtoc` reverts to the old format where `\chapter*` is not added to the ToC.

   Here is the code you'd need to automate this process (with some help from [`xparse`](//ctan.org/pkg/xparse)):

   ```
   \usepackage{xparse}

   \let\oldchapter\chapter % Copy \chapter into \oldchapter
   \NewDocumentCommand{\starchaptotoc}{s o m}{%
     \IfBooleanTF{#1}
       {\oldchapter*{#3}% \chapter*
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#3}% Add chapter title to ToC
       }
       {\IfValueTF{#2}
         {\oldchapter[#2]{#3}}% \chapter[.]{..}
         {\oldchapter{#3}}% \chapter{..}
       }%
   }

   \newcommand{\addstarchaptertotoc}{\renewcommand{\chapter}{\starchaptotoc}}
   \newcommand{\removestarchapterfromtoc}{\renewcommand{\chapter}{\oldchapter}}
   ```

I'd probably go with option (2).